# Duda MySQL Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, sql

Antes que nada, no soy un experto ni mucho menos con SQL (recién estoy dando mis primeros pasos sobre cómo se debería utilizarlo correctamente). Desde ya, sepan entender si cometo serios errores.
La duda es la siguiente:
Tengo 3 tablas: redes, personas, vendedores.

### Redes

```
campo       tipo        null    key   default   extra 
idred       int(11)     NO      PRI   NULL      auto_increment
fb          text        YES           NULL  
in          text        YES           NULL  
tw          text        YES           NULL
```

### Personas

```
campo           tipo        null    key    default  extra
idpersona       int(11)     NO      PRI    NULL     auto_increment
nombre          text        NO             NULL
apellido        text        NO             NULL
dni             int(11)     NO      UNI    NULL
direccion       text        NO             NULL
telefono        text        NO             NULL
email           text        YES            NULL
imagen          text        NO             NULL
fecha_alta      text        NO             NULL
num_redes       int(11)     YES     MUL    NULL
```

### Vendedores

```
campo           tipo        null    key     default     extra
idvendedor      int(11)     NO      PRI     NULL        auto_increment
usuario_nombre  varchar(45) YES             NULL
usuario_contra  varchar(45) YES             NULL
condicion       int(11)     NO              NULL
num_persona     int(11)     YES     MUL     NULL
```

Las claves foráneas en si son:

- vendedores.num_personas -> corresponde a personas.idpersona
- personas.num_redes -> corresponde a redes.idredes

Ambas con restricciones iguales (ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE).
El problema surge cuando intento eliminar directamente de la tabla vendedores:

```
DELETE FROM 'vendedores' WHERE vendedores.idvendedor='1';
```

Según tenía entendido, la restricción en cascada para la eliminación me eliminaría los registros en las otras tablas que 'compartan' esos datos.
¿Alguna manera de solucionar esto o bien debo eliminar registro por registro?
Desde ya, muchas gracias :).

**Nota**: si se precisan más datos, estoy al tanto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes de tener en claro cuales son los [tipos de Foreign Key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) que existen en MySQL

**On Delete Restrict**

La base de datos devolverá un error. Esto evita que los registros hijos queden huérfanos y conserven su relacion.

**On Delete Cascade**

Al Eliminar un registro este borrara todos sus hijos , como una Cascada

**On Delete Set Null**

Al Eliminar un Registro los registros hijos se actualizaran en **`NULL`** hay que tener en cuenta que los registros hijos permitan valores **`NULL`** de lo contrario te arrojara un error

**On Delete Set Default**

Esta restricción funciona de manera similar al tipo "on delete set null", excepto que, en lugar de establecer la columna FK de la tabla secundaria en null, la establece en el valor preestablecido por defecto de la definición de columna. Este valor predeterminado debe existir en la tabla primaria.

Teniendo en cuenta como funcionan los **Foreign Keys** creo que ya puedes actualizar tu base de datos a como quieres que funcionen al eliminar.

> Te recomiendo no eliminar ningun registro al menos que en realidad sean "registros basuras" debido a que creas tu base de datos para almacenar en el tiempo informacion, lo que recomiendan es utilizar un campo llamado inactivo, si este campo est en true en tu programa no lo puedes ver

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración y los consejos.
Daba por hecho que si eliminaba un registro que pertenecía a la tabla vendedores, como es padre de persona (y este a su vez, padre de social) se eliminarían "en cascada" (al tener la restricción en cascada para la eliminación).

Comment: esto tambien aplica para update

Comment: Claro, pero al eliminar un registro de la tabla padre no se eliminan los registros de las tablas hijas. Evidentemente, debido a mi inexperiencia, algo mal estoy haciendo, porque ya he consultado varias páginas y funciona muy bien con otros ejemplos. No se si me estaré salteando algún paso, alguna otra aclaración que necesiten para poder ayudarme a solucionarlo. PD: para este caso en particular, no influye demasiado si elimino o no los registros, pero entiendo de la necesidad de preservarlos aún cuando se "eliminen".

Comment: al eliminar un "abuelo" vas a eliminar todos los "padres" que tiene el "abuelo" si los "padres" tienen hijo y no tienen habilitado eliminar en cascada los "padres" no podran eliminar a sus "hijos" por eso se llama cascada fijate bien como lo estes creando